# Find the volume of the body obtained by rotating S around $y=1$-axis

Tags: calculus

- $y=x$, $x=1$; about $y=1$

The formula is $\pi \int f\left( x\right) ^{2}dx$. Then my answer is: $\pi \int _{0}^{1}(x-1) ^{2}dx$

**Can you check my answer?**

Comment: Isn't that figure a cylinder? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @applyb I think that there is no a problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the lines $y=x$ and $x=1$ do not bound a region, so there can be no answer. One may presume that the OP accidentally left out a third bounding equation but it is anyone's guess what that equation would be.

So I will take a wild stab at it and guess that the third bounding equation is $y=0$.

Then the volume of the solid of revolution about $y=1$ can be computed using either the annulus or the cylindrical shell method.

Using the annulus method

\begin{equation}
V=\int_0^1\pi(R^2-r^2)\,dx
\end{equation}

where $R=2$ and $r=1-x$.

Thus

\begin{eqnarray}
V&=&\int_0^1\pi\left[2^2-(1-x)^2\right]\,dx\\
&=&\pi\int_0^1(3+2x-x^2)\,dx\\
&=&\frac{11\pi}{3}
\end{eqnarray}

[image: Solid of revolution]